# After passing a function from a child component the value passed into the function is returned as a number instead of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am writing a simple program which takes selections off of a drawer and then show them as part of a recipe, but when the function from the parent is called the updated value sent to the parent is a number rather than the object.  I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong and would really appreciate some help.

Parent:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {listOfOils} from "./Constants/OilList";
import OilDrawer from "./Components/OilDrawer";
import OilMixCard from "./Components/OilMixCard";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            recipe: [],
            recipeName: ''
        }

    }

    addOilToRecipe = (oil) => {
        this.setState(() => {
                return {recipe: this.state.recipe.push(oil)}
            }
        )
    }

    setRecipeName = (name) => {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {recipeName: name}
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="App">
                <OilDrawer
                    addOil={this.addOilToRecipe}
                    oils={listOfOils}
                />
                {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.recipe))
                }
                {/*The value for recipe when printed in the OilMixCard in the console is 1*/}
                <OilMixCard
                    recipe={this.state.recipe}
                    updateName={this.setRecipeName}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Child:

```
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider'
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

class OilDrawer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            openDrawer: true
        }
    }

    // handleDrawerClose = () => {
    //     this.setState({openDrawer: false})
    // }

    render() {
        return (
            <Drawer

                className="oil_drawer"
                variant='persistent'
                anchor='right'
                open={this.state.openDrawer}
            >
                {/*<IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>*/}
                    {/*<ChevronRightIcon/>*/}
                {/*</IconButton>*/}
                <Divider/>
                <List>
                    {this.props.oils.map(oil =>
                        <ListItem
                            button
                            onClick={() => this.props.addOil(oil)}
                            key={oil.name}
                        >
                            <Avatar src={oil.image}/>
                            <ListItemText primary={oil.name}/>
                        </ListItem>
                    )}
                </List>
            </Drawer>
        )
    }
}

export default OilDrawer
```

Another Child which displays the recipe:

```
import React from 'react'
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

class OilMixCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Paper>
                <List>
                    {console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.recipe))}
                    {
                        this.props.recipe.map(oil =>
                            <ListItem
                                button onClick={() => this.props.addOil(oil)}
                                key={oil.name}
                            >
                                <Avatar src={oil.image}/>
                                <ListItemText primary={oil.name}/>
                            </ListItem>
                        )
                    }
                </List>
            </Paper>
        )
    }
}

export default OilMixCard
```

Comment: Well where's the code for `OilMixCard`?

Comment: I edited my original post and have included it at the bottom.

Comment: I'm sure that this isn't related with your current problem, but you are using `setState` incorrectly since it will only merge old and new state when receiving an object as first argument, when passing a updater function you should manually merge old and new state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `push` method on arrays return the added value rather than the final array. In your `addOilToRecipe` method, its the string in reference `oil` that gets set to `this.state.recipie`, when you do the following:

```
this.setState({ recipe: this.state.recipe.push(oil) });
```

Now when you call map on the string, you get individual numeric indexes.

Instead do something like this:

```
this.setState({ recipe: [...this.state.recipe, oil] });
```